# Перестал работать PHP WkHtmlToPdf

Tags: php, debian, wkhtmltopdf

### **Проблема #1 (Решено):**

После чистой установки Debian 7 + ISPManager 5 перестал работать phpwkhtmltopdf.

В консоли по команде

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.ru gog.pdf
```

всё работает отлично, но через скрипт phpwkhtmltopdf

```
$pdf = new Pdf('http://www.google.ru');
$pdf->saveAs('/gog.pdf');
print_r($pdf->getError());
```

выдаёт ошибку

> Segmentation fault.

Если использовать phpwkhtmltopdf уже на полную (добавлять свой CSS, добавлять настройки и т. д.) то выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> Failed without error message: xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0,
>   1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf --orientation 'Portrait' --margin-right '0'
>   --margin-left '1' --margin-bottom '5' --margin-top '10' --page-size 'A4' --use-xserver --user-style-sheet
>   '/path/to/pdf.css'
>   '/path/to/file.html'
>   '.pdf'

При этом до переустановки системы всё работало отлично. Могу предположить, что после переустановки я что-то где-то забыл включить, но что именно, понятия не имею. Может, у кого была подобная ситуация?

Вот полный объект:

```
mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf Object (

    [binary] => wkhtmltopdf
    [commandOptions] => Array
        (
        )

    [tmpDir] =>
    [ignoreWarnings] =>
    [version9] =>
    [_isCreated:protected] =>
    [_options:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [_objects:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [inputArg] => http://www.google.ru
                )
        )

    [_tmpPdfFile:protected] => mikehaertl\tmp\File Object
        (
            [_fileName:protected] => .pdf
        )

    [_tmpFiles:protected] => Array
        (
        )
    [_command:protected] => mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Command Object
        (
            [enableXvfb] =>
            [xvfbRunBinary] => xvfb-run
            [xvfbRunOptions] => --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24"
            [escapeArgs] => 1
            [escapeCommand] =>
            [useExec] =>
            [captureStdErr] => 1
            [procCwd] =>
            [procEnv] =>
            [procOptions] =>
            [locale] =>
            [_command:protected] => wkhtmltopdf
            [_args:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 'http://www.google.ru'
                    [1] => '.pdf'
                )

            [_execCommand:protected] => wkhtmltopdf 'http://www.google.ru' '.pdf'
            [_stdOut:protected] =>
            [_stdErr:protected] => Segmentation fault
            [_exitCode:protected] => 139
            [_error:protected] => Segmentation fault
            [_executed:protected] =>
        )
    [_error:protected] => Segmentation fault
)
```

### **Проблема #2:**

После ручной установки PHP Wkhtmltopdf стал выдавать пустые PDF, в выдаче он пишет:

```
[_stdOut:protected] => The switch --use-xserver, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.Loading page (1/2)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[===================>                                        ] 33%
[======================>                                     ] 38%
[============================>                               ] 47%
[==============================>                             ] 50%
[=====================================>                      ] 62%
[=======================================>                    ] 66%
[===============================================>            ] 79%
[=================================================>          ] 83%
[============================================================] 100%
Printing pages (2/2)                                               
QPainter::begin(): Returned false
[>                                                           ] 
Done
```

Я так понимаю, что тут ключевые слова `is not support using unpatched qt` и `QPainter::begin(): Returned false`. Но странно, Wkhtmltopdf у меня пропатченный, и из консоли всё работает, как надо. Может, кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: После "proc_open()" в "$pipe[1]" нашел ошибку "wkhtmltopdf: symbol lookup error: wkhtmltopdf: undefined symbol: _ZN12QWebSettings20setPrintingMediaTypeERK7QString " - возможно в этом все дело, но что это за символ такой?

Comment: привязка к какой-то библиотеке. вероятно, надо пересобрать программу.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен что решение именно в этом, но путем не одного десятка переустановок, получилось что QT надо устанавливать по https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/qt/archive/wk_4.8.7.zip

Я же ставил по
https://github.com/jcsalterego/wkhtmltopdf-qt/archive/staging.zip

Хотя возможно что решение было в другом. Но теперь все работает.